# New angularjs project is created inside Documents not where I wish

Tags: angularjs, node.js

When I run this command , the new project angular is created inside **Documents** not inside **workspace/first-app**

```
asus@asus-X541UJ:~/Documents/workspace/first-app$ sudo yo angular
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .yo-rc file in the parent directory fixed this problem.